# User cancellation error

Tags: users

When I delete/cancel a user account from admin, I got the attached error.
It is saying that the table `cache_entity_profile2` is not found. Yes, the table does not exist actually. I am using the modules [entity cache](http://drupal.org/project/entitycache) and [profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2).
The error is not generated every time, but very often.

[image]

Comment: you might want to post that in the issue queue for entity cache (assuming the error doesn't happen with entity cache disabled).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Most likely the error is because of entity cache.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem is which module's responsibility it is to maintain that table.
All relevant info and links are in this issue: https://drupal.org/node/1387268

Comment: The patch from comment #30 solved the problem for me.